# Difference between using Hi and Hey?

Tags: letter-writing

I am not a native speaker. I really want to know what's the difference between Hi and Hey in writing an email? In daily conversation? Is it too girlish or childish for a man to say hey in his email? What's the bottom line in using them?

Comment: *Hi* and *hey* are two different expressions, the first is the informal equivalent of *hello* whilst the second is used to grab somebody's attention as in "Hey, what's that unidentified flying object?", "Hey, did you see last week's episode of ...?"; "Hey man, how you're doing?" and "Hey man, how's it going?" You don't use *hey* to address someone in an email.

Comment: Thank you. Because I always see a lot of girls using that, that's why I ask.

Comment: Where are you from? Are you living in the US? *Hey* is not gender specific, it all depends what follows the exclamation, *Hey, I love your new lipstick shade*  and "Hey, let's go down the pub for a couple of drinks" :)

Comment: I am the down-voter; my reason for down-voting is that the question appears to be primarily a matter of seeking  sexual advantage and/or gender validation within, and validation for, a value system that despises the female sex.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Sorry about that, it's not my intention. I think it might be a phrasing issue. Could you please help me edit it. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I've been in the US for several years. I'm asian.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I grew up with the assumptions you presented in your comment. However, I have found that Americans under about 35 years of age tend to say _hey_ **instead of** _hi_, which they hardly ever say. It's a case of an invasive interjection.

Comment: @JohnLawler that's why I asked the OP where he was living? *Hey* is not a greeting that I read or hear from my British friends or family, instead *hiya* is frequently used in emails and in speech but that's quite different from *hey*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Actually, I see "hey" used as an email greeting quite a lot. But it's considered very informal, not something you'd use in a professional capacity or with strangers.

Comment: In my experience, "Hey" has been gaining ground as a greeting in the UK too.

Comment: @MattThrower and Rupe, do you address your colleagues and supervisors in emails with "Hey Tom"; "Hi/Hiya, Tom"; "Hello Tom/Thomas" or "Dear Thomas/Mr. X"? I tend to lean towards the second, but only because I have a good rapport with my colleagues and bosses.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I would not use "Hey" in a work setting - unless the content was personal (i.e. want to go for a beer after work?). It's not generally used with a name - you just open the mail with "Hey".

Comment: So *Hey* is used to grab the reader's attention, and it's short for: "stop what you're doing and listen to what I have to say" :))

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that's pretty much it.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't use it much, except with my kids, so I don't have intuitions, and this is getting subtle. Needs more sociolinguistic research, obviously. Seems vaguely like using the complementizer _that_ instead of a _Wh_-word in a relative clause; it works for restrictive relatives, but it doesn't have the referential chops to do non-restrictives.

Comment: @JohnLawler The etymology of *hi* is interesting. The OED has two senses. The first is the exclamation used to attract attention i.e. what has now become *hey*. I well remember (1950s) when *hi* was used in Britain in the same way that *hey* seems now to be the accepted form. Though the last OED example is 1897 - I'm not that old!) The second is *hi* as a greeting, which I feel certain is Native American in origin. At least the first example the OED gives is from 1862: *M. D. Colt Went to Kansas ix. 143   When out on the prairie, up galloped an Indian on his pony with his saluting ‘hi!’*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As a greeting, *Hey* is more informal than *Hi*. I wouldn't use *Hey* in an office e-mail.

*Hey* is not considered childish or girlish. Most commonly used amongst young men I'd guess.

Comment: This must be regional.  Adults in the UK don't use Hey, in fact it would be considered rude, more like an alternative to Oi.  Hi is quite informal already!

Comment: I am from the UK and in my 40s, and I find "Hey" very rude.  As James says, it's like someone shouting "oi!" at you.  Definitely not for business communication, especially with older people.

Comment: It's not being used to call for someone's attention in this context, I wouldn't ever use it that way either. It's more like a lazy _hi_.

Comment: @JamesRyan I'm from the UK and I'd use "Hey" with close friends, or people I see every day. (10 years ago I would have seen "Hey" as American, but not any more.) As Neil said, you don't shout it or say it abruptly, it's said slowly and lazily. Similar to how you'd pronounce "Hi" but possibly warmer. In summary, it could be generational (I'm late 20s and most of my friends are mid 30s) but I disagree that it's regional.

Comment: I just moved to the UK from North America and was about to send an email to an older man starting off with "Hey". Good thing I read these comments first! In North America, "Hey" is completely fine as long as you or the person you're talking to doesn't take themselves too seriously. In fact, being too formal in email communication there often comes across as not being personal.

Answer (score 14):

**E-mails**

*Hey* or *Heya* are much less formal. You could use them if you were writing to friends.

> Hey Dave, not spoken to you in a while. How're things? What've you been up to?

You could possibly use it in a more casual email (like a single question) to a colleague that you speak to often:

> Hey Bob, just wondering if you've had a reply from Customer X yet?

*Hi* is the standard greeting for office e-mails. If you're not sure, stick with *Hi*.

> Hi Dan,
>
> Thanks for the information on [foo]. Do you know whether item 10 is for all customers or just Y?
>
> I'll get back to you on [question] when I've had more time to look at the data.
>
> Regards,
>
> George

You could also use *Hi* for friends.

**Conversation**

*Hey* or *Heya* can be used to greet people you already know. Friends or colleagues. It's warmer than *Hi* so probably isn't suited to colleagues that you're less close to.

- > Hey Dave, glad you could make it. How're you?
- > Hey guys, what's up?

*Hi* can be used to greet people you already know, or those you don't.

- > Hi Bob, how's Sylvia?
- > Hi Kate, nice to meet you. How do you know Dan?

There is no gender differentiation in who can say either term, or who they are said to.

Comment: British vs American usage is different, I think. Also, missing category -- people you don't know and won't know after talking to them, like those working in retail.

Answer (score 3):

Hi is used to greet someone and is a shortened version of hello. "Hello George". "Hi Mary". Hey was used to beckon someone. "Hey boy! Come here!". It is in recent times that Hi became too formal whilst meeting friends and Hey somehow found it's way into such colloquial meetings. "Hey Mary, How have you been?" 
If you are going to be using the written word or an email, stick to using Hi.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as a native english speaker living in england, I occasionally greet my friends with any of: Hi, Hey, Hola, Yo, Dobradien, Ciao, or Wazzup, although of course *never* bonjour (I am english, after all)*.

In other words, when casually greeting a friend, or even when meeting someone in a casual setting, you can say pretty much anything. In an email or other written context, I would always use "Hi" or something more formal ("Dear X", "To whom it may concern", etc).

Nowadays, "Hello" tends to sound a little stilted, although no one would fault you for using it, especially if you have an accent.

Supplementary to this, I present for your consideration: [hot dog squirrel comet](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3582)

<sub>* This is a joke. England and France have a long history/tradition of rivalry.</sub>

Comment: Capital letters for English, England? Where's your pride? :)

Comment: You know that the hot dog squirrel comet article is citing work by *Christian <insert-french-word-here> Benoît*?!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mari-Lou A's statements, but *hey* can also be used for a very informal greeting, during an informal conversation. In an email, the person will write *dear X* or *hello* or *hi*.

Answer (score 0):

My observations are that hey is rapidly overcoming hi as an informal greeting, originally on a personal level, but increasingly in business environments where the parties already know each other.  There is a certain robustness to greeting a friend or colleague with "hey," making "hi" sound a bit effete--it is interesting that the original questioner got that backwards, thinking that hey sounded girlish.  BTW, the British commenters are not really qualified to comment on a question of evolving usage like this, since they speak British, which is a dialect, rather than English.  Current Standard English means American English.  The language of Shakespeare, referring to current, articulate, vigorous, expressive use of the English language, means American English, not what is spoken on the increasingly insignificant little island where the language happened to originate.

Comment: That must be why more language students travel to Ireland, for example, every year to learn English than go to the US to do so... interesting! Don't disagree with your hey/hi thing. Your ridiculous idea that some variety of English is better than another is very entertaining and good for a laugh. Cheers! :)

Comment: There is no such dialect as British English. I, an Englishman living in Lancashire, no more speak the same dialect of English as a Scot or someone from Wales than a New Zealander speaks Strine.